# Haskell: How to only generate .hi file with ghc?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I would like to generate an `.hi` interface file and **only** that (no object file, no code generation at all).

I tried

```
ghc -fno-code -ohi out.hi myfile.hs
```

and get

```
ghc: -ohi can only be used when compiling a single source file
```

which I don't understand since I have only given a single source file.

Comment: Why do I want to do that? Because I just want a type check, as fast as possible, and skipping code generation gives me a speed-up of at least factor 3.

Comment: If you just want to type check, skip the .hi file generation as well.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I would like to use that to speed up checking whole cabal projects ([see here](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1176)), where a dependency of an exectuable on the library requires the .hi files to exist.

Comment: See [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682584/2108477). In short, `-fno-code -fwrite-interface`.

Comment: @Kindaro Excellent, that works, in combination with `-c` as written by @AntonKovalenko. If you write that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @nh2 Doesn't it work without -c as well? I mean, `-fno-code` has the same effect, no?

Comment: @nh2 To my eyes, an invocation of `ghc -fno-code -fwrite-interface` on an individual source file works identically with or without '-c', while an invocation of `cabal build --ghc-options ...` fails in both cases, as `cabal` will attempt linking regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around 2014, there was an option added to GHC specifically for this. Now, you can invoke:

```
ghc -fno-code -fwrite-interface ...
```

It actually speeds up compilation by about a quarter in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-c` option, or else ghc wants to link, not just to compile:

```
ghc -fno-code -ohi out.hi -c myfile.hs
```

UPDATE: but it doesn't really help, because `-fno-code` prevents `.hi` creation.

```
ghc -o /dev/null -ohi out.hi -c myfile.hs
```

This one throws away the result of compilation. However, it will also avoid unnecessary compilation if `out.hi` is up to date.

Comment: Yes, this will give me the desired speed-ups for multiple runs, but I would like to skip the unnecessary step completely. If we find out that current ghc cannot do this, I will accept this as a workaround, though.