# Is there a way to only compile Haskell source to interface file, not further?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Usually, when `ghc` is compiling a source code, it will produce at least an `.o` (object) and a `.hi` (interface) file.

In the interest of diminishing compilation time, if I only need an interface file, can I somehow order `ghc` to abandon everything else and just give me said interface file? Or, otherwise, obtain that interface by any kind of lowly guile?

I found [this `ghc` user guide part](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html) and it says nothing of such. [This one](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/options-phases.html) doesn't even mention "*interface*" anywhere in its text. (In particular, `-fno-code` doesn't generate it.) It must mean there's no easy way. In [this question from five years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14306934/2108477), nothing floated up, but by chance things are different now?

Most likely, I expect it to take a hack to `ghc`. If so, I'd like directions:

- Is it reasonable to submit a feature request to [trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc), or (likely) I should rather go for it myself?
- How is `.hi` file distinct from something like `-ddump-types`, just binary?
- Is there certainty that composing a `.hi` file takes strictly less compilation stages than a complete `.o` file? (For example, if there are hashes of machine code fragments within `.hi`, the corresponding code will probably have to be generated, which means nothing is to be gained here.)

Otherwise, perhaps I can just extract related parts from `ghc` code so that I can then compile a `.hi` file from the output of `-ddump-types` or the like?

Comment: This is actually a fairly outdated user guide linked here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there is a flag `-fno-code -fwrite-interface` that does this. It actually cuts compilation time for even a simplistic example by about a quarter.

Comment: Can you also confirm that this sped up compilation? (By how much?)

Comment: @chi Kindly see edit!